# How can we conclude $h(x)$ is constant in Eisenstein's Criterion proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I came across the following proof of Eisenstein's criterion from the book Galois Theory by Joseph Rotman.

Let $f(x) = a_o +a_1x + ... +a_nx^n \in Z [x]$. If there is a prime p dividing $a_j$ for all i < n, but with p not dividing $a_n$ and $p^2$ not dividing $a_o$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Let $f(x) = g(x)h(x) = (bo + b_1x + ... + b_mx^m)(c_o + c_1x + ... + c_kx^k)$ we may assume that both g and h lie in Z[x]. By hypothesis, $p|a_0 = b_oc_o$ so that $p | b_0$ or $p | c_0$, by Euclid's lemma in Z; since $p^2$ does not divide $a_o$, only one of them is divisible by $p$, say, $p | c_0$  but p does not divide $b_o$. The leading coefficient $a_n = b_mc_k$ is not divisible by p, so that p does not divide $c_k$ (or $b_m$). Let $c_r$ be the first coefficient not divisible by p (so p does divide $c_o, ... , c_{r-1}$). If r < n, then $p|a_n$ and $b_oc_r = a_r - (b_1c_{r-1} + ... + b_rc_o)$ is divisible by p; hence $p | b_oc_n$ contradicting Euclid's lemma (because p divides neither factor). It follows that r = n, hence k = 0, and $h(x)$ is constant. Therefore, f(x) is irreducible.

Shouldn't we conclude that $g(x)$ is constant from $r=n$, because $h(x)$ would have degree $n$ and therefore $g(x)$ would have degree 0, otherwise the degree of $g(x)h(x)>n$.
How do we conclude $k=0$?

Comment: If $k=0$ then the polynomial $h(x)=c_0+\ldots+c_kx^k$ amounts to $h(x)=c_0$ which is constant

Comment: Yes, I know that but how do we conclude that $k = 0$?

Comment: Please don’t rely on images: they are not searchable (either within the site or with web search tools); they are usually no accessible (unless you typed a full description of the content, in which case you might as well just type it directly into the post); and many screenreaders cannot process them (making your post unavailable to people who use screen readers). The site includes extremely good math typesetting capabilities, so please avail yourself of them.

Comment: The sum of the degrees must equal $n$, so $r+k=n$. Once you know $r=n$, you know $k=0$.

Comment: I didn't know that about images, I will try to re-write the question.

Comment: Why does the sum of the degrees equal $n$, $r+k = n$? I can only see $k+m=n$.

Comment: My mistake; the image was too small in my screen (another reason to avoid them). It’s a typo: it should be either $k=n$ or $m=0$. This follows because $c_k$ is not divisible by $p$, $r$ is the smallest index for which $c_r$ is not divisible by $p$ (so $r\leq k$); we know $k\leq n$; and you just proved $r=n$. So $n=r\leq k\leq n$ proving $k=n$, hence $m=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a typo. It should be either “$m=0$” (instead of $k=0$) or “$k=n$” (instead of $k=0$).

This follows because we know $c_k$ is not divisible by $p$, $k\leq n$, and $r$ is the smallest index such that $c_r$ is not divisible by $p$. Therefore, $r\leq k\leq n$. Since you just established that $r=n$, it follows that $n=r\leq k\leq n$, so $k=n$ and since $m+k=n$, then $m=0$.